# Detect a certain number of turtles on neighborhood

Tags: netlogo

I have 2 kinds of mice, a normal and a special. They are eaten by the cats.
Now I want to make the special mice harder to be eaten. So I want it only to be eaten when it is surrounded by at least 2 cats.
Is there a way to check that with a `if` or something?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you have so far for the part where the cats eat the mice? It'll be a lot easier to help you if we can suggest ways to modify your existing code.

Comment: You need to specify what does surrounded mean. In your context it seems surrounded means neighboring patches. I also think surrounded could mean if cats are on the current patch (since mice are very small compared to cats!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mice-own [is-special]

to step
  ask mice 
  [
     let num-surrounding-cats count neighbors4 with [count cats-here > 0] 
     ifelse is-special
     [if num-surrounding-cats > 1 [*eaten logic*]
     [ if num-surrounding-cats > 0 [*eaten logic*]]

  ]
end
```